# Possible to include pipeline name when Azure Alert trigger alert for Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-monitor

I have Azure Alert to Azure Data Factory. It gives hyperlink to Azure Monitor when pipeline run fails.

Is it possible to include name of Data Factory Pipeline or any other description like activity error message in Alert message?

It would help to speed troubleshooting.

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I create Alert for pipeline failed metrics and followed below steps to get the pipeline name in Alert message:

In dimension > name I selected the name as **all pipelines**

[image]

**Output**

You will get all FailuerType and name of pipeline in the Alert mail.

[image]